# How to setup library-application including extend/redeclare in OpenModelica?

Tags: openmodelica

I have Modelica code divided in a small library DEMO_v11.mo and an application D11_APP7.mo  The application code include parts that adapt interface of the library to the application using: import-extend-redeclare. It all works in JModelica. Now I want to set it up in OpenModelica but I do not know how to handle my two different files. Browsing through the documentation I could find little help.

I have before managed to bring in a library and in OpenModelica add graphical notation and then compose a new model based on components from the library. 
However, now I need to do a more “advanced” import that extend-redeclare the imported models. Thus my problem is how to do this more “advanced” part.

Appreciate some advice, or suggestion on where to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this questions I have found is both easy and difficult.

The easy part is that you should in OpenModelica load both the library and application code in the same way using command “File/Open Modelica/Library File(s). Then the library and the application land side by side, sort of. The icons for them appear in the pane to the left and below the MSL library Modelica. The application code can then import (and redeclare) from both the loaded library and from MSL if needed in a similar way.

The difficult part is that here seems to be bugs in OpenModelica when you refer to models in two (or more) steps instead of one.  This question I discuss with OpenModelica support.

A code that works to import as described above are library DEMO_v15 and application D15_app7 and shown below (and slightly modified from DEMO_v11 and D11_app7 mentioned and described in another thread).

```
   package DEMO_v15

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium2
            replaceable constant String name = "Two components"    "Medium name";
            replaceable constant Integer nc = 2                    "Number of substances";
            replaceable type Concentration = Real[nc]              "Substance conc";
            replaceable constant Real[nc] mw = {10, 20}            "Substance weight";  
            constant Integer A = 1                                 "Substance index";
            constant Integer B = 2                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium2;

        package Medium3 
            import M2 = DEMO_v15.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name="Three components"                           "Medium name",
                 nc=3                                              "Number of substances",
                 mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30})                            "Substance weight",
                 redeclare type Concentration = Real[nc]           "Substance conc");
            constant Integer C = 3                                 "Substance index";   
        end Medium3;

        connector LiquidCon3
            Medium3.Concentration c                                "Substance conc";
            flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                              "Flow rate";
        end LiquidCon3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Equipment dependent on the medium  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment
            replaceable connector LiquidCon
            end LiquidCon;

            model PumpType
                LiquidCon inlet, outlet;                                                     
                RealInput Fsp;
            equation
                inlet.F = Fsp;                                         
                connect(outlet, inlet);                          
            end PumpType;

            model FeedtankType
                LiquidCon outlet;                                  
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(outlet.c,1);
                parameter Real[medium_nc] c_in (each unit="kg/m3") 
                                = {1.0*k for k in 1:medium_nc}     "Feed inlet conc";                        
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 100               "Initial feed volume";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Feed volume";
            equation    
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    outlet.c[i] = c_in[i];
                end for;
                der(V) = outlet.F;               
            end FeedtankType;

            model HarvesttankType
                LiquidCon inlet;                                   
                constant Integer medium_nc = size(inlet.c,1);
                parameter Real V_0 (unit="m3") = 1.0   "Initial harvest liquid volume";
                parameter Real[medium_nc] m_0 
                      (each unit="kg/m3") = zeros(medium_nc)       "Initial substance mass";
                Real[medium_nc] c                                  "Substance conc";
                Real[medium_nc] m 
                      (start=m_0, each fixed=true)                 "Substance mass";
                Real V(start=V_0, fixed=true, unit="m3")           "Harvest liquid volume";
            equation
                for i in 1:medium_nc loop
                    der(m[i]) = inlet.c[i]*inlet.F;
                    c[i] = m[i]/V;
                end for;
                der(V) = inlet.F;               
            end HarvesttankType;
        end Equipment;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    //     Control 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Control
            block FixValueType
                RealOutput out;
                parameter Real val=0;
            equation
                out = val;
            end FixValueType;
        end Control;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of package Equipment to Medium3 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //  package Equipment3 = Equipment(redeclare connector LiquidCon=LiquidCon3);   // Just shorter

        package Equipment3
            import DEMO_v15.Equipment;
            extends Equipment(redeclare connector LiquidCon=LiquidCon3);
        end Equipment3;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        model Test
            Medium3 medium;
            Equipment3.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment3.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Equipment3.PumpType pump;
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
        end Test;

    end DEMO_v15;
```

And application code:

```
   encapsulated package D15_app7

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Interfaces  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
        import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;

        package Medium7
            import M2 = DEMO_v15.Medium2;
            extends M2
                (name = "Seven components"                      "Medium name", 
                nc = 7                                          "Number of substances",
                mw = cat(1,M2.mw,{30,40,50,60,70})              "Substance weight",
                redeclare type Concentration = Real[nc]         "Substance conc");
            constant Integer C = 3                              "Substance index";
            constant Integer D = 4                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer E = 5                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer F = 6                              "Substance index";  
            constant Integer G = 7                              "Substance index";  
        end Medium7;

        connector LiquidCon7
            Medium7.Concentration c                             "Substance conc";
            flow Real F (unit="m3/s")                           "Flow rate";
        end LiquidCon7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //     Adaptation of library DEMO_v15 to Medium7  
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package Equipment7
            import DEMO_v15.Equipment;
            extends Equipment(redeclare connector LiquidCon=LiquidCon7);
        end Equipment7;

    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    //     Examples of systems 
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        import DEMO_v15.Control;

        model Test
            Medium7 medium;                 // Instance not necessary but helpful for user interface
            Equipment7.PumpType pump;
            Equipment7.FeedtankType feedtank;
            Equipment7.HarvesttankType harvesttank;
            Control.FixValueType Fsp(val=0.2);
        equation
            connect(feedtank.outlet, pump.inlet);
            connect(pump.outlet, harvesttank.inlet);
            connect(Fsp.out, pump.Fsp);
        end Test;

    end D15_app7;
```